# mysql - get number of occurrences from "different" query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering how could I get the number of occurrences of a common string from different results (or using OR in my query, as example below).

table example:

```
id | name | rank 
1 | name1 | 1
2 | name1 | 1
3 | name2 | 1
4 | name3 | 1
5 | name1 | 2
6 | name1 | 2
7 | name3 | 2
```

Now, I need to count number of occurrences for rank = 1 and rank = 2, without duplicating  the  count.

doing something like this:

```
SELECT  name, COUNT(DISTINCT name) 
AS name_num FROM table WHERE rank = 1 GROUP BY name;
```

results is

```
name1 | 1
name2 | 1
name3 | 1
```

perfect, but now I need to include some other result (i.e. rank = 1 OR rank = 2) and get the occurrences from each name, without duplicating it.

the wanted result for query example using table example and rank = 1 OR rank = 2 should be:

```
name1 | 2
name2 | 1
name3 | 2
```

I'll try to explain the result I want:

```
name1 is present when rank = 1 (+1) and when rank=2 (+1);
name 2 is only present when rank=1
name3 is present when rank = 1 (+1) and when rank=2 (+1);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Name,
       Count(Distinct Rank) as Ranks  
       from TableName
       where Rank=1 or Rank=2 
       Group By Name
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93b26/2)

Comment: it was missing a DISTINC:
Select Name,
       Count(DISTINCT Rank) as Ranks  
       from TableName
       where Rank=1 or Rank=2 
       Group By Name. Looks like it works. (I'll make some tests - thank you anyway!
P.S: Can you explain me why it doesn't work when Count (DISTINCT name) but it does work when Count (DISTINCT rank) ?

Comment: @dmartinez count(Distinct Name) count the by ditinct name in group by result and count(Distinct Rank) count the by ditinct Rank

Answer (score 2):

You want `COUNT(DISTINCT rank)`, not `COUNT(DISTINCT name)`. Since you're grouping by name, there will only be one distinct name in each group.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(DISTINCT rank) name_num
FROM table
WHERE rank in (1, 2)
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Name,
       Count(distinct Rank) as Ranks  
       from TableName
       where Rank=1 or Rank=2 
       Group By Name
```

This is what you asked for?